# How to get the final Stop Loss price on a closed trade using MetaTrader for Python?

Tags: python, trading, algorithmic-trading, forex, metatrader5

The MetaTrader for Python [documentation](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5) shows users can only use the [history_orders_get](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5historyordersget_py) and [history_deals_get](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/integration/python_metatrader5/mt5historydealsget_py) functions to access historical trade data, rather than a simple history_positions_get function.

On MT5, trades are split into 5 elements;

1. Position
2. 'In' Order
3. 'In' Deal
4. 'Out' Order
5. 'Out' Deal

This can be visualised better from the MT [Manager View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkjls.png)

This is fine for execution trades etc, but for users wanting to create custom account reports in python, knowing the final stop loss value when the position was closed is valuable.

On the MetaTrader for Python library, it seems we only have access to the orders and deals, and so here is all the history data I can retrieve for position 275:

```
TradeOrder(ticket=275, time_setup=1657825200, time_setup_msc=1657825200024, time_done=1657825200, time_done_msc=1657825200053, time_expiration=0, type=0, type_time=0, type_filling=0, state=4, magic=0, position_id=275, position_by_id=0, reason=3, volume_initial=12.5, volume_current=0.0, price_open=0.0, sl=138.876, tp=140.266, price_current=139.154, price_stoplimit=0.0, symbol='EURJPY', comment='Long Breakout PERIOD_H1', external_id='')

TradeDeal(ticket=285, order=275, time=1657825200, time_msc=1657825200053, type=0, entry=0, magic=0, position_id=275, reason=3, volume=12.5, price=139.154, commission=0.0, swap=0.0, profit=0.0, fee=0.0, symbol='EURJPY', comment='Long Breakout PERIOD_H1', external_id='')

TradeOrder(ticket=276, time_setup=1657868538, time_setup_msc=1657868538652, time_done=1657868538, time_done_msc=1657868538652, time_expiration=0, type=1, type_time=0, type_filling=1, state=4, magic=0, position_id=275, position_by_id=0, reason=4, volume_initial=12.5, volume_current=0.0, price_open=139.243, sl=0.0, tp=0.0, price_current=139.243, price_stoplimit=0.0, symbol='EURJPY', comment='[sl 139.243]', external_id='')

TradeDeal(ticket=286, order=276, time=1657868538, time_msc=1657868538652, type=1, entry=1, magic=0, position_id=275, reason=4, volume=12.5, price=139.243, commission=0.0, swap=-45.15, profit=800.41, fee=0.0, symbol='EURJPY', comment='[sl 139.243]', external_id='')
```

As you can see, only the Order data gives info on the SL position, and only for the In Order. For this trade, the only SL price given is 138.876, however when looking at the POSITION from an MT5 statement, we can see that the position was closed with a stop loss of 139.243:

[MT5 Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvXBR.png)

Technically speaking, the final stop loss SHOULD be available on the 'Out' Deal, but for some reason you cannot extract the SL or TP values from the Deals, just Orders.

I would appreciate some ideas on how to get the final stop loss price if it is possible to do this!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using `history_deals_get()`, it seems that "price" reflects the actual execution price of the exit. I have the below example (in my case, the response is just converted into a dict) where I was able to verify in the MT5 Terminal that the execution took place at `24413.5` (with the stop loss level actually set at 24415.00).

```py
{
    "ticket": 60015958,
    "order": 62916005,
    "time": 1676999856,
    "time_msc": 1676999856976,
    "type": 1,
    "entry": 1,
    "magic": 10,
    "position_id": 62895194,
    "reason": 4,
    "volume": 1.0,
    "price": 24413.5,
    "commission": 0.0,
    "swap": 0.0,
    "profit": -269.75,
    "fee": 0.0,
    "symbol": "BTCUSD",
    "comment": "[sl 24415.00]",
    "external_id": "",
}
```

In your case, it tells `price=139.154`, which is close to the value that you indicate. As regards the reason for the minor (vs. 139.243) deviation, I have no clue :)

Comment: Please create your own question for the part I deleted.